# How I list oly txt files of a directory?

Tags: python, tkinter

How I list oly txt files of a directory?...
how i filter to txt files

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("D:\hacking\python") if isfile(
    join("D:\hacking\python", f))]

print(onlyfiles)
```

Comment: Just add "and f.endswith(".txt")" in your list comprehension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `and` condition in the list comprehension to check for the file extension as follows:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir("D:\hacking\python") if isfile(
    join("D:\hacking\python", f)) and f.endswith(".txt")]

print(onlyfiles)
```

The `.endswith()` function is pretty self-explanatory; it checks if a string *ends with* a given substring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function function `glob` from module `glob`, which supports wildcards and returns **full path names**. If you are certain that all paths ending in `.txt` are always regular files (or if you don't care and you just want all paths ending in `.txt` regardless of what type of path it is), then the code is simply:

```
import glob

onlyfiles = glob.glob(r"D:\hacking\python\*.txt")
```

Otherwise:

```
import glob
from os.path import isfile

onlyfiles = [x for x in glob.iglob(r"D:\hacking\python\*.txt") if isfile(x)]
```

Note: `iglob` returns an iterator rather than a list and is therefore more efficient to use in this case.

And if you do not want full path names:

```
 import glob
 from os.path import isfile, split

 onlyfiles = [split(x)[-1] for x in glob.iglob(r"D:\hacking\python\*.txt") if isfile(x)]
```